# How to implement routing function between compound module vectors (including routers, hosts, mobile modules, etc.)?

Tags: omnet++, inet

How to implement routing function between compound module vectors (including routers, hosts, mobile modules, etc.)? For example, how do you connect internal and external compound module vectors? How does the composite module in the middle of the network forward data?

1.I am using omnet++5.4.1 and inet4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

2. I am using satellite simulation module-os3. here are the satellite module code and SatSGP4 network code,omnetpp.ini code.

```py
package os3.base;

//import inet.base.NotificationBoard;
import inet.mobility.contract.IMobility;
import inet.networklayer.ipv4.RoutingTableRecorder;
import inet.node.inet.Router;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import os3.mobility.Norad;
import os3.mobility.SatSGP4Mobility;
import inet.node.ethernet.Eth1G;

module Satellite
{
    parameters:
        @nodes();
        @node; //because of MobilityBase initialization
        string satelliteName = default(""); // Parameter for satellite name
        string mobilityType = default("SatSGP4Mobility"); // Define mobility module
        // Transmit Power of satellite (7dBW as example for CospasSarsat system)
        double transmitPower @unit(dBW) @display("i=device/satellite;bgb=324,226") = default(7dBW); // Symbol
        @display("t=$satelliteName;bgb=688,367");
    gates:
        //input radioIn; // Input gate
        //output radioOut; // Output gate
        inout ethg[];

    submodules:
        mobility: <mobilityType> like IMobility { // Module for mobility (parent class -> BasicMobility), BasicMobility -> IMobility
            @display("p=57,109");
        }
        //mobility : SatSGP4Mobility {
        //     parameters:
        //     @display("p=194,103");
        //}
        //        notificationBoard: NotificationBoard { // Module for event notification
        //            parameters:
        //                @display("p=221,94");
        //        }
        NoradModule: Norad { // Module for transformation between omnet and libNorad
            parameters:
                @display("p=51,36");
        }
        host: StandardHost {
            @display("p=204,101");
        }
        router: Router {
            @display("p=204,233");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        host.ethg++ <--> Eth1G <--> router.ethg++;              
        // towards other areas 
        router.ethg++ <--> ethg++;
}
```

```py
package os3.examples.SatSGP4;

import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import os3.base.Satellite;
import os3.base.MissionControlCenter;
//import inet.world.radio.ChannelControl;
import inet.physicallayer.common.packetlevel.RadioMedium;
import os3.base.CNI_OS3;
import inet.node.ethernet.Eth100M;
//
// Network SatSGP4 enables satellite movement on worldmap
//
network SatSGP4
{
    parameters:
        int numOfSats; // Number of satellites
        int numOfMCCs; // Number of Mission Control Centers

        @display("bgi=background/background_earth,s;bgb=2160,1080");

    submodules:
        satellite[numOfSats]: Satellite {
            parameters:
                @display("p=116.315,384.11;r=10,,#707070;i=device/satellite_l");
        }
        MCC[numOfMCCs]: MissionControlCenter {
            parameters:
                @display("p=300.255,292.13998;i=misc/building;r=10,,black");
        }
        channelcontrol: RadioMedium {
            parameters:
                //numChannels = 2;
                @display("p=300.255,64.92;i=misc/sun");
        }
        cni_os3: CNI_OS3 {
            @display("p=80,70,i;i=old/bluebox");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=562.64,67.625");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        satellite[0].ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> satellite[1].ethg++;      
        satellite[1].ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> satellite[2].ethg++;
}
```

```py
[Config SatSGP4]
network = SatSGP4

SatSGP4.satellite[*].mobilityType = "SatSGP4Mobility"

**.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxX = 2160m

**.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxY = 1080m

**.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m
#-----------------------------radiomedium seetings---------
**.channelcontrol.propagation.typename ="ConstantTimePropagation"
**.channelcontrol.analogModel.typename ="ScalarAnalogModel"
**.channelcontrol.pathLoss.typename ="FreeSpacePathLoss"
#-------------------------------nic setting ---------------------

# tcp apps
**.satellite[0].host.numApps = 1
**.satellite[0].host.app[*].typename = "TcpSessionApp"
**.satellite[0].host.app[0].active = true
**.satellite[0].host.app[0].localAddress = ""
**.satellite[0].host.app[0].localPort = -1
**.satellite[0].host.app[0].connectAddress = "SatSGP4.satellite[2].host"
**.satellite[0].host.app[0].connectPort = 1000
**.satellite[0].host.app[0].tOpen = exponential(0.1s)
**.satellite[0].host.app[0].tSend = 0s
**.satellite[0].host.app[0].sendBytes = 1MiB
**.satellite[0].host.app[0].sendScript = ""
**.satellite[0].host.app[0].tClose = 0s

**.satellite[2].host.numApps = 1
**.satellite[2].host.app[*].typename = "TcpSinkApp"
**.satellite[2].host.app[0].localAddress = ""
**.satellite[2].host.app[0].localPort = 1000

# NIC configuration
**.ppp[*].queue.typename = "DropTailQueue" # in routers
**.ppp[*].queue.frameCapacity = 10  # in routers


[General]
# location of NED files
ned-path = ../../../inet/src;../../src/os3;.;
# location of images for GUI
image-path = ../../images/os3
#
sim-time-limit = 1500s

# Network parameters
**.updateInterval = 10s   # Interval to update the satellite positions on the map
**.numOfSats = 3          # Number of satellites used in simulation. ATTENTION! Must be smaller or equal to number of satellites in choosen TLEfile

# Parameters for UserConfig
**.userConfig.frequency = 1e9Hz
**.userConfig.min_snr = 0dBHz

#
# Parameters for WebServiceControl
#
# Insert you own API Key. You can register at http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx
**.webServiceControl.apiKeyWeather = ""
# Insert your own username from http://www.geonames.org/login
**.webServiceControl.usernameAltitude = ""
# (default = 100) Maximum number of saved altitude values. Be careful when changing!
**.webServiceControl.altitudeCacheThreshold = 100
# (default = 10) Maximum number of saved TLE data strings. Be careful when changing!
**.webServiceControl.tleCacheThreshold = 10
# (default = 10) Maximum number of saved weather data strings. Be careful when changing!
**.webServiceControl.weatherCacheThreshold = 10

#
# Parameters for WeatherControl
#
# (default = -1 means using live weather data) Precip per hour (unit mm/(m2*h))
**.weatherControl.defaultPrecipPerHour = -1

#
# Parameters for Norad
#
# Provide the filename of the TLEs. Used by Webservice if GUI not used,
# must fit the names from http://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/xxx.txt
*.satellite[*].NoradModule.TLEfile = "gps-ops.txt"

#
# Parameters for Calculation
#
# Provide the name of the Table for the Rain parameters. DO NOT CHANGE!
**.calculation.rainTableFile = "../../data/TablespecRain.csv"

#
# Parameters for Satellite
#
# (default = 7dBW) Transmit power of satellites (Can be choosen individually for each satellite, see MCCs for example)
*.satellite[*].transmitPower = 10dBW
# default = "", satelliteName is only used if a specific satellite from a TLE file should be used instead of the first numOfSats.
#*.satellite[0].satelliteName = "GPS BIIA-10 (PRN 32)"

#
# Parameters for Channelcontrol (INET module) 
#
# Variable. Maximum transmit Power of a Base Station found in Germany (Usingen).
# Default(20mW) Maximum sending power used for this network (in mW)
*.channelcontrol.pMax = 100000W

#----------------------------------------------------
# Mission Control Centers all over the world
#----------------------------------------------------

**.numOfMCCs = 4

# Algier
SatSGP4.MCC[0].mobility.latitude = 36.46
SatSGP4.MCC[0].mobility.longitude = 3.03
SatSGP4.MCC[0].cityName = "Algier"

# Ourgla
SatSGP4.MCC[1].mobility.latitude = 31.57
SatSGP4.MCC[1].mobility.longitude = 5.20
SatSGP4.MCC[1].cityName = "Ourgla"

# Parana, Argentinia
SatSGP4.MCC[2].mobility.latitude = -31.43
SatSGP4.MCC[2].mobility.longitude = -60.30
SatSGP4.MCC[2].cityName = "Parana"

# Rio Grande
SatSGP4.MCC[3].mobility.latitude = -53.47
SatSGP4.MCC[3].mobility.longitude = -67.42
SatSGP4.MCC[3].cityName = "Rio Grande"
```

I want the host of satellite[0]  transport tcp datas to the host of satellite[2],but it can't do it.when i run ini file,in satellite[0],host send arpREQ to router,router receive arpREQ and send arpReply to host,but when host once again send SYN to router,the router send ICMP-error-#3-type3-code0.Did  the links is wrong or setting ini is wrong or other wrongs？Thank you in advance for your help.